# Probability and Expectation People in Line

Tags: probability

A group of *n* people all have distinct heights. They are waiting in a straight line at the bank (one person in front of the other), with all orderings of the people equally likely.  A person can see ahead to the front of the line if they are taller than everyone in front of them.

- (a) What is the probability that the *i*th person in line can see to the front of the line (where the first person is at the front of the line, the second person is behind the first, etc.)?
- (b) What is the expected number of people in line that can see to the front of the line? (Hint: Linearity of expectation.)

There are *n!* ways to arrange those people in line. For the first person to see in line:  *nC1*, then for the *i*th person it is going to be *nCi*?

I am not sure how to approach (b)?  Any hint or advice is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Define *indicator random variables* $Y_1,Y_2,\dots, Y_n$ as follows. Let $Y_i=1$ if the $i$-th person can see all the way to the front of the line, and let $Y_i=0$ otherwise. Then $W=Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$ is the number of people who can see all the way to the front of the line. We want $E(Y_1+\cdots+Y_n)$, which by the linearity of expectation is $E(Y_1)+\cdots+E(Y_n)$.  Note that the $Y_i$ are *not* independent. But linearity of expectation holds in *all* cases.

We have $\Pr(Y_i=1)=\frac{1}{i}$.  For among the first $i$ people, the one in position $k$ is just as likely to be the tallest in the group as any other. So 
$$E(W)=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n},$$
the $n$-th harmonic number.

Comment: Why is P(Yi=1)=1/i, and not 1/i!  ?

Comment: Your suggested $1/i!$ is the probability the first $i$ people are lined up **exactly** in order of increasing  height.  But for the $i$-th person to see all the way to the front, it doesn't matter whether the people in front of her can see, all that matters is that she is the tallest. And as I wrote in the answer, if you concentrate on the first $i$ people, the tallest is just as likely to be first as second as third and so on.  Just like if you deal $5$ cards in a row, and you get a royal flush in spades, the Queen of spades is just as likely to be fist dealt, second dealt, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. So essentially the answer to (a) is P( ith person can see to the front of the line) = 1/i ?

Comment: Yes, I did not do (a)  separately since that was dealt with in solving (b).

Comment: You can also get the $\frac{1}{i}$ the slow way. The probability the second person can see is clearly $1/2$, For the third to see, the orders of height have to be $1,2,3$ or $2,1,3$, two possibilities out of $3!$, so $\frac{1}{3}$. For the fourth to see, any order for the first three is fine, as long as $4$ is tallest, probability $3!/4!=1/4$. And so on. I would rather do it the fast way.

Comment: You are welcome.